# login failed connecting to SQL Server with AttachDbFilename and User Instance

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am developing ASP.NET 2.0 application using SQL Express 2005. I have attached my database with the application.

The Connection string:

```
 <add name="WCMIRConnectionString"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
  connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=&quot;\App_Data\WCMIR.mdf&quot;;Integrated Security=True;Trusted_Connection=no;User Instance=True" />
```

When trying to connect the following error appears :

> Cannot open database "dp-name" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'Machine\useID'.

How can this error be resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved
Connection string must be like :

Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|DB.MDF;" +
            "Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";

Answer (score 1):

First I think the connection string should be with `|App_Data|` not `\App_Data\`
Second Make sure that this user has permission on this folder and on this DB

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need the AttachDbFileName if your database is already attached, but you should include InitialCatalog to indicate which database you would like to connect to.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to use "|" instead of backslash in your code.